# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")

Tags: bash, for-loop, jq

When i run this code, i get 
./file.sh: line 23: ((: j<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<"). The  $orgs+$i.json in the below code will generate files if it consists data, otherwise thise file wont be generated. The orgs and repos are from the file which i passed. Once the json file is created with data, then i will need to pull some fields like commit, repo, author, file fields from that json file. I will attach the json file format from which i'm trying to pull values.

Json file data looks like in below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opwJi.jpg)

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$IFS,
usr='*************'
pwd='*************'
url='*************'
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET 
"https://$usr:$pwd@$url" |grep login|cut -d ':' -f2|sed 's/,//g'|sed 
's/"//g' >> MHEOrgs.txt
File=./MHEOrgs.txt

while read orgs; do

#orgs= $i
curl -s --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET --user 
"$usr:$pwd" $url/$orgs/repos?page=[1-100] >> $orgs+Repos.json
jq -r '.[].name' $orgs+Repos.json >>$orgs+Repolist.json
user="https://$usr:$pwd@********/$orgs/"
repos=`cat $orgs+Repolist.json`
for i in $repos;
do
    echo $user"$i".git
    #Below commabd will perform scan operation on the githubrepos and 
    generates multiple json files
    ~/go/bin/gitleaks --repo=$user"$i" --report=$orgs+$i.json
     #Now i wanted to get below values from each file generated above.
     numsecs=$(jq ".|length" $orgs+$i.json)
     for ((j=0;j<$numsecs;j++))
     do
        commit=$(jq -r ".[$j]|.commit" $orgs+$i.json)
        author=$(jq -r ".[$j]|.author" $orgs+$i.json)
        file=$(jq -r ".[$j]|.file" $orgs+$i.json)
        repo=$(jq -r ".[$j]|.repo" $orgs+$i.json)
        if [ "${commit}" != "null" ]; then

        echo "\"$repo\"," "\"$file\"," "\"$author\"," "\"$commit\",">> 
        gitleaks-scan-results.csv
        else
        echo "No leaks found"
        fi


      done


    done

done < $File
```

Comment: A good [mcve] is **minimal**: It has only the shortest code needed to reproduce a given error.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest making it a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking a question here; that way we don't need to pick through potential quoting issues &c. and figure out which ones are and aren't actually related to a given problem.

Comment: ...btw, I'd suggest `bash -x yourscript` to log each line as it runs; that way you can see what command is actually being run to populate `numsecs`, and rerun that yourself by hand to debug.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest trying to cut down the number of `jq` invocations. There's no good reason to run `jq` once per author, once per commit, etc; you can run jq *just once*, and have it extract everything in the exact format you need.

Comment: ...for example: `jq -r '.[] | [.repo, .file, .author, .commit] | @csv'`

Comment: Some commands in the code in your question are split across lines without a backslash continuation character. See in particular the two `curl` commands.

Comment: ...or, if you *really* want to do processing in bash: `while IFS=$'\t' read -r repo file author commit _; do echo "Repo: $repo; file: $file; author: $author; commit: $commit"; done < <(jq -r '.[] | [.repo, .file, .author, .commit] | @tsv')` -- maybe using NULs instead of tabs if you want to be more cautious.

Comment: BTW, uploading content as images is not acceptable here -- someone can't reproduce a bug with data from an image unless they retype it, and re-typing risks introducing extra bugs (or masking other ones, as when two characters look alike but have different actual values). See also [Why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens if `numsecs` isn't actually set to a (single integer) number.

One way that can happen is if your JSON file doesn't have any records in it at all; or if it has more than one (which would mean you'd have several numbers in `jq`'s output, which bash can't correctly parse to a single number).

---

#### Some Examples

The zero-object document case:

```
$ numsecs=$(jq '. | length' <<<'')
$ declare -p numsecs
declare -- numsecs=""
$ for ((j=0;j<$numsecs;j++)); do break; done
-bash: ((: j<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

The multi-object document case:

```
$ numsecs=$(jq '. | length' <<<$'[1,2]\n[3,4]')
$ declare -p numsecs
declare -- numsecs="2
2"
$ for ((j=0;j<$numsecs;j++)); do break; done
-bash: ((: j<2
2: syntax error in expression (error token is "2")
```

Comment: When i executed my script, i get this jq error, when it does not find the json files it is looking for. The script doesn't create a file if there is no data. However my jq statements will search for all files and pull data. So, when it doesn't find the file thats when i get the error.